# Python PyGame jump code running when it shouldnt

Tags: python, pygame

I couldn't find anything about this but for some reason my jump code keeps running when I hold the button down, so it basically makes you fly even when it shouldn't, please help.

```
    while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
               x_change = -5
            elif event.key ==  pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP and jumped == 0:
               y_change = -10
               jumped = 1
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change = 0
    if x < 32:
        x += 5
    if x > (display_width-32) - char_width:
        x += -5
    if y < 32:
        y += 5
    if y > display_height - char_height:
        y = display_height - char_height
    if y < (display_height-32) - char_height:
        y += 5
    if y > (display_height-32) - char_height:
        jumped = 0
    x2 = x
    y2 = y + char_height
    x3 = x2 + (26)
    if gameDisplay.get_at((x2,y2)) == (0,0,255) or gameDisplay.get_at((x,y)) == (0,0,255) or gameDisplay.get_at((x3,y2)) == (0,0,255):
        y+= -5
        jumped = 0
```

(the variable "jumped" gets reset when you collide with the floor btw)

Comment: I think you're going to have to show more code. I suspect your problem is in the handling of what happens when the character is in the air rather than in this code.

Comment: The obvious places to check are where you set `jumped = 0`.  Put some `print` statements around those or use your debugger to verify that those are behaving as you expect.  The collision code looks particularly suspicious to me.

Comment: You don't seem to use `y_change` anywhere.

Comment: These lines seem odd: `if y > (display_height-32) - char_height:
        jumped = 0`. I'd guess this is setting jumped to 0 when your character is in the air.

Answer (score 0):

We don't really have enough code to judge, so I'm just guessing right now. The code you show here modifies the y-position of your character, to make it "jump". If the character continuously stays at that elevation, perhaps you should modify the y-position somewhere else to bring the character back down.

Comment: sorry, i updated it to show more of the code, sorry again new here